# Why retarded time doesn't matter in Larmor's formula?

Tags: electromagnetism, power

There's a usually way to deduce Larmor's formula,

$$P = \frac{\mu_{0}q^{2}a^{2}}{6\pi c}$$

It starts with the fact that the Poynting vector is $\vec S= \frac{1}{\mu_{0}}\vec E \times \vec B$, and because $\vec B=\frac{1}{c}\vec n_{ret}\times \vec E$ (where $\vec n_{ret}$ means evaluated in $t_{ret}$), then $\vec S = \frac{1}{c\mu_{0}}\vec n_{ret}E^{2}$. Then it is replaced just the part of $\vec E$ related to radiation (just the second term in the image below) in this expression for $\vec S$, and with that $\vec S$ it is possible to get $\frac{dP}{d\Omega}$ to finally get Larmor's formula (first derivation in Wikipedia use this idea). My question is, since $\vec E$ was evaluated in $t_{ret}$, should Larmor's formula also be evaluated in $t_{ret}$? I mean, to me should be $a_{ret}$ insted of $a$. In every similar demonstration this is ignored, but why?

[image: Electric field of a moving charge]

Comment: The Wikipedia article states that larmors formula is for nonrelativistic particles, this means their velocity is very small as compared to $c$. I'd imagine it's easy to approximate away those terms.

Comment: @Triatticus  For nonrelativistic particles just affect in that you can take $\beta$ -> $0$, but the $a_{ret}$ (that is in $\dot{\beta}$) will still appear in $\frac{dP}{d\Omega}$, and therefore will still appear once you integrate to get $P$.

Comment: Yes the $\dot{\beta}$ is included in the derivations on Wikipedia, did you not see this as the case for the nonrelativistic version? The only approximation is that $\beta=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, at time $t$ the Poynting power due to particle's field (assumed to be the retarded solution of Maxwell's equations, and the other fields due to other sources are assumed to be insignificant) flowing out of a large sphere of radius $R$ centered at the point where the particle was at the past time $t-R/c$ is related to acceleration of that particle at the past time $t-R/c$. Thus value $P(t)$ is quadratic function of the value $a(t-R/c)$.